# Varnish with Magento 1.8.1 Community editon not getting cache results

Tags: caching, varnish, magento-1.8, varnish-vcl

I'm newbie to Varnish Cache. I've installed Varnish 4 ( latest version) on Cent OS server successfully and configured perfectly. I'm also getting X-Varnish, Via 1.1 varnish - v4 in Response header. I've found everything working perfectly. If I stop varnish, website stops which seems correct.

My question is, eventhough varnish is configured correctly I'm not having enough speed. I thought, I'm not getting varnish cache result, it looks server always called backend server to get results. Normally, without varnish it takes 3-4 seconds to get results. After installing varnish, It takes same amount of time.

**Resonse header**

> Accept-Ranges bytes **Age 0  Cache-Controlno-store, no-cache,
>   must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0** Connectionkeep-alive
>   Content-EncodinggzipContent-Typetext/html; charset=UTF-8DateFri, 01
>   Aug 2014 14:08:51 GMTExpiresThu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00
>   GMTPragmano-cacheServerApache/2.2.15
>   (CentOS)Set-Cookiefrontend=rfdi8hd6kq136puafk93lm0ra7; expires=Fri,
>   01-Aug-2014 15:08:51 GMT; path=/; domain=www.usapooldirect.com;
>   httponlyTransfer-EncodingchunkedVaryAccept-Encoding,**User-Agent Via
>   1.1 varnish-v4 X-Powered-By PHP/5.3.3X-Varnish**

**Request Header**

> Accepttext/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml;q=0.9
>   ,*/*;q=0.8Accept-Encodinggzip,
>   deflateAccept-Languageen-US,en;q=0.5Connectionkeep-aliveCookiefrontend=rfdi8hd6kq136puafk93lm0ra7;
>   external_no_cache=1;
>   adminhtml=pt3bt6t30m4vtqdsm1ldv716v7Hostwww.usapooldirect.com
>   Refererhttp://www.usapooldirect.com/User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (X11;
>   Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0

Thank you,

Ankit

Answer (score 2):

You should check Varnish hits with help of Varnishstat.

You can also put below code which you can check in browser if it got served from Varnish cache or backend.

```
sub vcl_deliver {
if (obj.hits > 0) {
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT ("+obj.hits+")";
} else {
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
    #    set resp.http.X-Cache-Hash = obj.http.hash;
}
return (deliver);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for hint. I've found X-Cache - MISS. How would I fix it? Would you please suggest me any clue?

Answer (score 2):

Whatever module you'll use to improve caching, as long as Magento is involved - even if it is only for determining what data to load from its cache - it will be slow. Varnish is always been a solution to speed up Magento.

But after Magento 1.8.1, Varnish cache is practically becomes useless. You can see here [how you can configure Varnish Cache with Magento 1.8.1](http://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-configure-varnish-cache-magento/)! and above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below sample Varnish file.

```
backend default {
.host = "localhost";
.port = "80";
}

sub vcl_recv {
if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
remove req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
set req.http.x-forwarded-for = req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
} else {
set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
}

if (!req.backend.healthy) {
unset req.http.Cookie;
}

if (req.backend.healthy) {
set req.grace = 60s;
} else {
set req.grace = 24h;
}

if (req.request != "GET" &&
req.request != "HEAD" &&
req.request != "PUT" &&
req.request != "POST" &&
req.request != "TRACE" &&
req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
req.request != "DELETE") {
return (pipe);
}
if (req.request == "POST") {
return(pipe);
}
if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
return (pass);
}

if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg)$") {
remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
}
elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
}
elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
}
}       else {
remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
}

if (!req.backend.healthy) {
unset req.http.Cookie;
}
if (req.http.Cookie) {
return (pass);
}
return (lookup);
}

sub vcl_pipe {
return (pipe);
}

sub vcl_pass {
return (pass);
}

sub vcl_hash {
hash_data(req.url);
if (req.http.host) {
hash_data(req.http.host);
} else {
hash_data(server.ip);
}
return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hit {
return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_miss {
return (fetch);
}

sub vcl_fetch {
if (beresp.status == 404 || beresp.status == 503) {
set beresp.ttl = 0s;
return (hit_for_pass);
}
if (!req.backend.healthy) {
set beresp.ttl = 1h;
unset beresp.http.set-Cookie;
}
if (beresp.http.Set-Cookie) {
return (hit_for_pass);
}
set beresp.grace = 24h;
return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
if (obj.hits > 0) {
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cache = "HIT";
}
else {
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cache = "MISS";
}
}

sub vcl_init {
return (ok);
}

sub vcl_fini {
return (ok);
}

sub vcl_error {
return(deliver);
}
```